# Combine multiple Sepa transaction groups

Tags: civisepa

We are starting to use CiviSEPA for a client, but a bit appalled that it seems to create groups of transactions per day and not for , say... the next two weeks all together.

Considering we have imported over 2000 already existing mandates with different collection days, we would have to treat groups per every day of the month.
Now I wonder, is this by design and just  the way this should work or is there a way to treat the transaction for a given period?